# MongoDB "point not in interval of [ -180, 180 )"

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have objects like the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f7f0d64e4b0db1e18790f10"),
    "location" : [
        0.674081,
        23.473
    ],
    "name" : "Item Name"
}
```

If I try and create a 2D index on the location field, I get an error:

```
> db.Place.ensureIndex({location:"2d"});
point not in interval of [ -180, 180 )
```

I've tried finding documents that are out of bounds but this returns no results:

```
> db.Place.find({"location.0":{"$lte":-180, "$gte":180}});
> db.Place.find({"location.1":{"$lte":-180, "$gte":180}});
```

I've also tried the following queries to make sure:

```
> db.Place.find({"location":{"$size":0}}).count();
0
> db.Place.find({"location":{"$size":1}}).count();
0
> db.Place.find({"location":{"$size":2}}).count();
363485
> db.Place.count();
363485
```

What other approaches can I use to find the bad document(s)?

For information I'm using MongoDB version 2.0.2 on 32 bit Linux (yes, I know that's not good enough for prod). The documents were imported by a Java document where the location objects are only ever represented as `double` primitives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries aren't quite right. You need:

> db.Place.find({"location": {"$lte":-180 } })

And

> db.Place.find({"location": {"$gte":180 } })

Comment: I guess it's 'and' by default, then? Could he 'or' them into a single query or is that not possible with MongoDB?

Comment: @Rup you can do `{$or: [{location:{$gte:180}},{location:{$lte:-180}}]}`

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar issue, and I've been able to pinpoint that ensureIndex breaks when one of lat/lon are exactly equal to -180 or 180. Look for those cases if you want to get around this issue, otherwise it looks like there's a fix: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/86b5b89c2785f3f45ad2674f48fe3189c137904c